# Git push action is not working when pushing from git action container

Tags: github-actions

I have an action on master branch which on push/merge builds a package, uploads it to PyPI then checks out to develop branch, bumps version in develop branch and pushes to the origin of develop branch. Develop branch has an action that listens to push/merge and does a snapshot release.
When I push to develop the develop action works perfectly and does a snapshot release, but when master branch pushes, **push is successful** but the action does not get triggered. What am I missing?
Both actions are added below.

```
name: Build and Upload Package to PyPI | Master Branch

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.5'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install setuptools wheel twine
          pip install GitPython
          pip install bumpversion
      - name: Strip 'snapshot' from version
        run:  sed -i 's/-snapshot//g' setup.py
      - name: Build and publish
        env:
          TWINE_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.PYPI_USERNAME }}
          TWINE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PYPI_PASSWORD }}
          TWINE_REPOSITORY_URL: https://pypi.domain.com
        run: |
          python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
          twine upload dist/*
      - name: Bump Verison and Push to develop
        run: |
          git stash
          git config --local user.email "name@email.com"
          git config --local user.name "username"
          git checkout develop
          python bump_version.py
          cat .bumpversion.cfg
          git remote set-url --push origin https://username:$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/repo/path
          git push origin develop
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

```
name: Build and Upload Package to PyPI | Develop Branch

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop

jobs:
  bumpTag_build_and_publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.5'
      - name: Install dependencies for setup
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install setuptools wheel twine
      - name: Build and publish
        env:
          TWINE_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.PYPI_USERNAME }}
          TWINE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PYPI_PASSWORD }}
          TWINE_REPOSITORY_URL: https://pypi.domain.co,
        run: |
          python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
          twine upload dist/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` is **intentionally** not allowed to trigger workflows. As seen in [documention](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#about-workflow-events):

> (...) if an action pushes code using the repository's `GITHUB_TOKEN`, a new workflow will not run even when the repository contains a workflow configured to run when push events occur.

If you need your automagic push to be "visible" by workflows, you need to create [Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line), add it to [repo secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets), and use that instead of `GITHUB_TOKEN`.

Note that GitHub assumes that you know what you're doing, if you use non-stock token - which means preventing possible infinite loop is on you. While it's not a case in your scenario *for now* (develop branch does not push anything), it's worth to remember in case one of workflows will change some day.